# How to call git_merge_file_from_index when one of the entries doesn't exist?

Tags: libgit2

The function `git_merge_file_from_index` takes three `git_index_entry*` as arguments (`ancestor`, `ours`, and `theirs`). If one of these is `null` then the function crashes, however such a situation is actually legitimate:

Suppose we have a commit `base`, and two child commits descended from it called `foo` and `bar`. If a file exists on `base`, and commit `foo` removes that file whilst commit `bar` modifies it, then merging `bar` into `foo` would result in a conflict where the `ours` `git_index_entry` does not exist.

How should we get the merge result in this type of situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a legitimate situation - but there's not much to do from the perspective of the file content. git itself (and libgit2's higher-level `git_merge` functions) will keep the content in the modified file but mark it as an edit/delete conflict.

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): foo.c deleted in HEAD and modified in branch1. Version branch1 of foo.c left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

The `git_merge_file` functions are basically wrappers over git's (and libgit2's) xdiff implementation, which does a file-level diff.

One could make an argument that libgit2's `git_merge_file_from_index` should have replicated this behavior and allowed an empty branch. This would align with the merge stages in the index for this particular type of conflict:

```
100644 33e0cb25e00b89f3bd9feeb51eb7b62033c54d67 1   foo.c
100644 d38ce0fa2aa34b529512f9bbda853d44e8461caf 2   foo.c
```

Since I wrote this code 7 years ago, I honestly don't remember at this point if there was a good reason to omit this behavior or not. At the API level surface, there's no way to indicate (today) that the file was just taken from the modified side and that there was an edit/delete conflict, but I don't think that there's any reason why this use case couldn't be added.

In the meantime, assuming that you want to emulate git's behavior with these conflicts, you will need to check for yourself if you're in an edit/merge conflict (ancestor at stage 1 and either an ours at stage 2 xor a theirs at stage 3) and take the contents from the modified side.

Comment: OK thanks, yeah this is what I am doing now, getting the merge result is easy enough.
Seems like unnecessary extra code to write, but I think more worrying is that the crash is unexpected, and it is easy to cause bugs from this.

Comment: It `GIT_ASSERT`s — which will either return an error indicating that you’ve missed a parameter, or properly `assert`, depending on how the library was compiled. The latter, of course, will abort your program. https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/936b184e7494158c20e522981f4a324cac6ffa47/src/libgit2/merge_file.c#L287